# Reload detail view when table cell is deleted - Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a split view controller (master-detail). I'm optimizing it for the iPhone 6 Plus.

Here's the issue. When you select a cell, it performs a show-detail segue and displays the cells information in the detailed view. However, when you delete a cell, the detailed view keeps the cells info even though the cell no longer exists.

Here's an example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

    //code that deletes my cell/not needed for example

    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Left)

    let splitController = self.splitViewController!.viewControllers
    self.detailViewController = splitController.last? as? detailedController
    if let detail = detailViewController {
        detail.title = "Select an item" 
        //detail.title is a variable in the view controller
        //on the views "viewDidLoad" it sets a label.text as title.
        }
    }
}
```

I want perform the action: detail.title = "Select an item", so that the view is no longer displaying the deleted cell. I tried making a new segue through code. No luck.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Make sure your segue that sets the detail view controller has an identifier.  In the sample *Master-Detail* project the identifier is `"showDetail"`.  You can find the identifier by selecting the segue in the *Document Outline View* of the project, and then looking in the *Identifier Field* in the *Attributes Inspector* for the segue.
2. Call this segue programmatically when you delete a row:

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       if editingStyle == .Delete {
           // Call showDetail when in a splitViewController and 2 view controllers
           // are present
           if self.splitViewController?.viewControllers.count == 2 {
              self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
           }
           ...
   ```
3. In your `prepareForSegue` make sure you check the selected row.  When you call the segue from the cell deletion code no row will be selected and `indexPathForSelectedRow()` will return `nil`:

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
           if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
               // set up destination view controller in the normal way
               ...
           } else {
               // No row was selected which means either this is the initial setup
               // or we came here from the row delete code
               let splitController = self.splitViewController!.viewControllers
               self.detailViewController = splitController.last? as? detailedController
               if let detail = detailViewController {
                   detail.title = "Select an item"
                   ...
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Note:  If your detail view controller has a default state for when `detail.title` is not set, and this default state is what you want your destination view controller to look like if no row has been selected, then you don't even need the `else` clause in `prepareForSegue`.  This is the case for the sample *Master-Detail* iOS app.  It is only necessary to call the segue programmatically from the edit code, and it all just works.

Comment: That works. Now a weird issue occurs. That does the trick when in landscape. But if I'm in portrait, when I delete a cell, it runs a segue to the detail (which I don't want). Should I be applying rules based on the device rotation?

Comment: I updated my answer to check for the presence of 2 view controllers when showing the detail view controller.  It isn't a good idea to check orientation because it is possible to not display the master and detail together in landscape (on iPhone 6 for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Don't go through segue mechanics unnecessarily because it gets messy. Instead, hold on to the detail view controller in prepareForSegue, the same way that viewDidLoad holds on to it (in the default master/detail template). Then set `self.detailViewController.detailItem = nil` after your call to `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`. Then in the detail view controller when you receive nil restore the views back to showing the default message when there is no item.

This pattern will set you up perfect for when you do UI State Restoration because you'll be able to set the detailItem on the detailViewController in the same way but from MasterViewController's `decodeRestorableStateWithCoder` decoding the `@"CurrentDetailItem"`.